# Is it possible to disable HAXM feature for an AVD based on Intel x86 CPU?

Tags: avd-manager, intel-haxm

In Android Studio V3.5, I created some AVDs which are based on Intel x86 CPU. 
But I failed to start any of them because any HAXM devices couldn't be found.

I have enabled VT-x in my BIOS setting. When I tried to install 'Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager V7.0.5', it reported "failed to configure driver unknown error. failed to open driver.".

My PC is Windows 7 64-bit. I couldn't find any solutions.

So, is it possible to disable HAXM feature for an AVD based on Intel x86 CPU?

Answer (score 0):

The Android `emulator.exe` has a lot of [command-line options](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options).

The one you need is `-accel`:

```
-accel <mode>

Valid values for mode are:
  auto - Determine automatically if acceleration is supported and use it when possible (default).
  off  - Disables acceleration entirely, which is primarily useful for debugging.
  on   - Force acceleration. If KVM or HAXM isn't installed or usable, the emulator won't > start and prints an error message.
```

Therefore you should use `-accel off`

For more details: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html

Comment: Thank you sir.
But in general, we start an AVD in the AVD Manager other than command line. 
In fact, I tried to find some option for this in myAVD.ini. But I failed to find any.